# Notification after Video playback in mobile safari

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I am trying to play some videos in a `UIWebView` and required to get some feedback when the video playback is finished, without any user interaction. I am looking for something similar to `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification`, but in `UIWebView`. Appreciate if anyone can share a work around.

Comment: have you found a solution ? because i have the same probleme. my playback start behind my webview i would try to intercepte this for set the alpha to 0

Comment: how do you play the video in you UIWebView?

Comment: @draiis I didnt manage to find a resonable solution to this issue. You may check the below link for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964731/notification-of-youtube-video-completion-in-iphone-app/5162638#5162638

Comment: @Nick, Try this link http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html

Comment: hey bros:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518719/how-to-receive-nsnotifications-from-uiwebview-embedded-youtube-video-playback

Answer (score 1):

I can't vouch for all video types but when I play a YouTube video in a `UIWebView` I can capture the event when the user presses 'Done' by subscribing to a private notification type:

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerDidExitFullscreen:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];`

This works in iOS 4.3 and 5.0.