# Get notifications when a Dailymotion video is played into a UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I'm currently showing a dailymotion url directly into a UIWebview.
When tapping on the thumbnail image, the video starts playing in fullscreen mode.

The problem is: when the video stops playing or the user tapps the "done" button, the original thumbnail has disapeared from the UIWebview, making it impossible to launch the video again.
I would like to control when the video has finished playing or the user has tapped the done button to reload the UIWebView.

**I've been looking around and playing with the Notification center but I couldn't get any response, can you tell me what code I should use ?**

loading the video

```
    NSURLRequest *requestObject = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xh7cgv_cine-pocket-a-candidate_creation"]];
[self.webv loadRequest:requestObject];
```

notification catch

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayerDidExitFullscreen:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification
                                           object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification
                                           object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playbackDidFinish:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

thanks,
Louis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

corresponding to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288375/event-on-view-displayed-change-youtube-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller) the MediaPlayer doesn't send out any notifications when started from within the UIWebView (no source given however). you could try these hacks: [visible-hidden events hack](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/82868-uiwebview-youtube-player-how-detect-end-movie-ipad.html), [timed key window checking-hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964731/notification-of-youtube-video-completion-in-iphone-app/5162638#5162638), [subview events-hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718606/mpmovieplayercontroller-fullscreen-movie-inside-a-uiwebview). If you had luck, please share some code!