# Get notification when play button appears in embedded video with UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

i'm using webviews into my app to embed videos, in this way

```
    NSString *embedHTML = @"<iframe width=\"300\" height=\"250\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/.....\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML];
    [_webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

I'd like to get notified when the play button appears, in order to create and stop an activity indicator... I've used

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

but it's not sufficient... when the webview finishes loading and the activity indicator stops, the playbutton appears 2-3 seconds later...
How can i synchronize the activityindicator stop with the playbutton appearance?
Thanks

Comment: Check this post . It looks similar -->
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964731/notification-of-youtube-video-completion-in-iphone-app

Comment: Thank you, but that post is about determining if the player window is still active or not... I'm interested only in the playbutton appearance...